# AS3 navigateToURL(); javascript function not firing when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, dom

I have a problem I cannot seem to solve. I am using AS3's navigateToURL(); function to call a simple javascript function. At the moment it just alerts the first parameter. The problem is, when this function is placed inside of the $(document).ready(function(){..}) block it does not fire. Example of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function mapLink(aVar){
      alert(aVar);
    };
  });
</script>
```

Example of simple AS3 call to function:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('Javascript: mapLink("'+mapObject.tooltipMoreLink+'");'), '_self');
```

When the function is placed OUTSIDE of the jquery code, it works fine. Why does it need to be inside of the jquery code you may be asking? I need the jQuery DOM selectors to manipulate certain dom elements based on the value of 'aVar' in my javascript function.

Any guidance is welcomed with an open mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eh. this is what the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class was designed for.

You issue has to do with scope. Your function is scoped to the jquery object, and not globally, so it is invisible to your call. If you need jquery selectors, then you could easily set the flash var independently, followed by the jquery routine.

**update**

maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't this be as be easy as:

```
function externalCall(param){

     $(domElement).doSomething(param);

}
```

?

I wouldn't think this need be tied to the jq ready function. I mean, if flash has already loaded, and the user is interacting, then *certainly* the ready event has long since fired successfully.

Hope that helps. I'm not sure I'm following exactly what you're trying to do ;)

...
btw - I really would look into ExternalInterface, NavToURL may work, but you can call your js directly with the former method.

Comment: Not sure I understand when you say set the flash var independantly. It is event driven, and the value is only passed through to the function on certain actions performed in the flash movie, hence my function needs to retrieve the value of the parameter aVar (sent from flash) and performe various DOM manipulation based on that value, which is variable and ever-changing. Appreciated the help.

Comment: Bosworth99 - Worked a treat. Appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because you have created a function inside the `DOMReady Event`
that is `$(document).ready` and calling it from outside the scope of the function.

You can access jQuery DOM Selectors from anywhere provided you have referenced jQuery.js in your page.

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mapLink(aVar){
      alert(aVar);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have jQuery called in the head of the document already, and this extra javascript function lives further down the page, in the body. Fact it, even if I put the function OUTSIDE of any jquery loaded events, it still does not seem to work. Even if I define it as you have above, and write this in the function: $('#europe').hide(); where 'europe' is an existing div, it has no effect. Why? I have defined (and used) jQuery selectors previously in my head section. This baffles me... Thanks for your response.

Comment: @webfac: there is no reason why this shouldn't work. please post more code if you can.

Comment: it is indeed working, was a typo on my behalf. Appreciate the help! Thank you